# Does this RegExp from Google Analytics actually do anything?

Tags: javascript, regex, google-analytics

Here's the section of code:

```
var 
[...snip...]
ye=/^(?:(?:https?|mailto|ftp):|[^:/?#]*(?:[/?#]|$))/i,
```

This regular expression is used twice, both times with `ye.test(a)`. And yet, I've found no strings that it *doesn't* match. I find that hard to believe, but
does this `RegExp` really match every string imaginable?

Demonstration:

```js
var ye = /^(?:(?:https?|mailto|ftp):|[^:/?#]*(?:[/?#]|$))/i;
console.log(ye.test("askjvhlkauehavkn"))
console.log(ye.test("/"))
console.log(ye.test("https:"))
console.log(ye.test("mailto/L:"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(?:https?|mailto|ftp)` matches `http` or `https` or `mailto` or `ftp` followed by
`:|[^:/?#]*`, which is alternative: `:` or anything but `:/>#`, zero or more times, and then followed by `(?:[/?#]|$)`, which means one of `/?#` or end of the string (`$`).

It will match `mailto:`, `ftp:`, `https:`, `ftpasda` (any string starting with `ftp`, `https`, `http`, `mailto` followed by a colon or any number of anything but `:/>#`).

**UPDATE**

After checking, it occurs that that alternation outside the non-capturing group applies not only to a colon, but also to whole group as well. So, if `mailto` or any string in the alternation doesn't match, regex engine will try matching pattern on the other side of mentioned alternation. This is example of string that won't match: `:///////`. [Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/vMED3s/1)

Comment: Doesn't concatenation have precedence over `|`, meaning that `(?:https?|mailto|ftp):` is the first "either-or" group and not just `:`? Because it seems to match the string `"ahnwwc"` too.

Comment: I'd just figured that out and was writing an answer, but you beat me to it. I'll use my wording in my big write-up, but I'll link to your answer. Thanks!